# Increase/Reduce max.poll.records dynamically

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Using Apache Kafka client from Java, is there any way to change a `Kafka consumer` config once has been created?.

I want to `increase/reduce` `max.poll.records` depending of the number of consumers in the cluster.

The only way is destroy, and recreate the consumer?. If that's the case, is bad since create a new consumer it will take time, and also the warmup.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but you would need to call `consumer.close()` then create a new instance with new config properties.

I'm not sure what you mean by "warmup/take time" since your JVM would already be "warm" and the network connection to bootstrap to Kafka and fetch shouldn't be "slow".

If you really want to control resource utilization in Kafka cluster, use throttling quotas at the server side, rather than force clients to modify properties at runtime.

Comment: Thanks, but then I was right, and the only way is close the current consumer and create an new one. Thanks, I will explore the throttling quotas, but this is for just a very specific use case.

Comment: Also another question, can be sure that when use consumer.close() Kafka it will do drain connection, and it will wait until all messages has been consumed right?

Comment: Consumed, yes, I think so (or rather, "fetched"), but not necessarily processed.